# How can I interpolate columns with unknown values for geocoordinates using meshgrid?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation, nan

I have a dataframe that I have merged with latitude, longitude, and values for chlorophyll concentration and temperature at those coordinates.

Dataframe 1:

```
    lat             lon      chlor    temperature   salinity
0   15.020831   -99.979164  0.177225    29.689999   NaN
1   15.020831   -99.937492  0.166649    29.619999   NaN
2   15.020831   -99.895828  0.162154    29.584999   NaN
3   15.020831   -99.854164  0.168426    29.574999   NaN
4   15.020831   -99.812492  0.180328    29.539999   NaN
... ... ... ... ... ...
215419  31.979166   -78.187492  0.260021    25.719999   NaN
215420  31.979166   -78.145828  0.275804    25.875000   NaN
215421  31.979166   -78.104164  0.247142    25.674999   NaN
215422  31.979166   -78.062492  0.265501    25.869999   NaN
215423  31.979166   -78.020828  0.263538    25.974998   NaN
```

The salinity dataset that I used, however, took measurements at different latitude and longitude values, as seen here:

Dataframe 2:

```
         lat      lon   salinity
605120  15.125  -99.875 0.000000
605121  15.125  -99.625 34.809124
605122  15.125  -99.375 29.729925
605123  15.125  -99.125 30.312372
605124  15.125  -98.875 31.037935
... ... ... ...
701683  31.875  -79.125 0.000000
701684  31.875  -78.875 0.000000
701685  31.875  -78.625 0.000000
701686  31.875  -78.375 0.000000
701687  31.875  -78.125 0.000000
```

How can interpolate the salinity values based on a 3-dimensional mesh to match the latitudes and longitudes of the first Dataframe, perhaps using meshgrid or an ML algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

If your two data set contains exact the same geo point (e.g: `lat, lon = 15.020831 -99.979164` in both data set), you can just perform a join on those columns.

However, it does not looks like it is. Then it is a regression problem: predict `salinity` with given `lat, lon`.

You can try [Gradient Boosting Regressor from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-gradient-boosting-regression-py). It is pretty straightforward. Just fit on train data set, predict on test then measure your loss and decide if it's ok. Finally apply the model to your data set with nan values.